# How to make a click of the list image trigger a click of the link inside that list element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I have an unordered list containing links.

I styled the list so that there is a "**`Click Me`**" image to the left of the link.

```
ul 
{ 
    list-style-image:url(/images/ClickMe.png)
}
```

*The problem is*: when the user clicks on "**`Click Me`**", they are not redirected and nothing happens.

**How do I make a click of the list image trigger a click of the link in that list element?**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="someurl">Some Url</a></li>
    <li><a href="someotherurl">Some Other Url</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a CSS problem I think, because the list bullets are not actually part of the a tag. You can cheat by making the links "wide left" to include the bullets like this (see the [jsfiddle snippet](http://www.jsfiddle.net/zp8QU/)):

```
ul
{ 
    list-style: disc;
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always make the item clickable through jQuery:

```
$("li").click( function (evt) {
    location.href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
});
```

Comment: +1 However, if javascript is disabled the bullets are still not clickable. Good option if you cannot use some CSS trick or don't want to test your trick on all browsers available.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a better way to do it but this works by making the link size so that it includes the bullets to the left of the link.

```
a{
  margin-left: -2em;
  padding-left: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the list to have those bullets, you can do it also without lists by making the links "list-item" displays:

```
<style>
a{ 
    display:list-item;
    list-style-image:url(/images/ClickMe.png);
    list-style-position:inside;
}
</style>
<div style="padding:12px;">
  <a href="someurl">Some Url</a>
  <a href="someotherurl">Some Other Url</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zp8QU/

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, this also works, but does not pass validation, does anyone knows if there's a correct way of doing it?

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <a href="someurl"><li>Some Url</li></a>
        <a href="someotherurl"><li>Some Other Url</li></a>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: It's not allowed to have anything other than li's inside an ul (first level) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul